# ¿Saber si se realiza algo en la DB desde el programa?

Tags: java, sql

Deseo detectar cuando se realiza un registro en mi base de datos, eso a nivel de bases de datos es un trigger pero a nivel de programación, como podria verificar si en cierta tabla se acaba de realizar un insert? trabajo con JAVA (version 8), SQL SERVER 2014 y con Netbeans 8.2

Answer (score 2):

Lo que indicas se conoce como reactividad. Los motores de datos tradicionales no implementan alguna manera directa de que las aplicaciones conozcan si su información ha sido modificada. Tras decir esto, lo que quieres realizar no es imposible, pero resulta complicado y convendría entender el costo, los riesgos, los problemas potenciales, evaluar cómo cubrir todos estos elementos y con todas las cartas sobre la mesa, evaluar si realmente vale la pena implementarlo.

Una idea inicial puede ser tener una aplicación X que puede ser invocada desde línea de comandos y que envíe algún tipo de mensaje a tu aplicación Y, ya sea por sockets o algún otro medio (p.e. invocar un servicio REST). Una vez que tengas X construido, la idea es instalarla en el mismo OS donde reside tu servidor SQL Server y que, desde el trigger en tu tabla, puedas invocar un comando que ejecute X con los parámetros necesarios. X toma esta información y la envía a Y. Ojo que esto tiene terribles puntos de fallo:

- Si el trigger falla, puede que se invoque (o no) a X.
- Debes asegurar qué pasa si los parámetros a enviar a X no son los correctos o tiene data inválida p.e. `null`.
- X debe soportar leer los parámetros y posiblemente transformarlos antes de enviarlos a Y.
- La comunicación entre X e Y no debería perderse.
- Debes tener forma de rastrear que los parámetros llegaron a Y correctamente.
- Si estás dentro de una LAN, quizás no necesites asegurar los canales de comunicación entre X e Y. Caso contrario, hay que tenerlo en cuenta.
- Una vez implementado, evaluar el rendimiento bajo carga de operaciones que disparen el trigger, así comprobar el throughput de tu arquitectura.

Otra alternativa es usar una base de datos reactiva (No SQL) que sí puede notificar a las aplicaciones en caso de suceder algún evento como el mencionado. Por ejemplo [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com). Esto, claramente, requiere de un cambio fuerte a nivel arquitectónico y que también merece su evaluación.

Si no quieres ir por el modelo reactivo, puedes usar el modelo tradicional de tener un cron que consulte la tabla o tablas que requieras y evaluar si ha cambiado. En caso de detectar cambios, tu aplicación puede realizar las acciones correspondientes.

La decisión es tuya.

---

Al parecer, SQL Server ofrece [Query Notifications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server) para que **una aplicación .Net** (no Java) pueda recibir notificaciones cuando los datos de un query se hayan modificado. Esto facilitaría la implementación de usar una aplicación X y tu aplicación Y. Cabe resaltar que X tendría que estar escrito usando .Net (C#, VB .Net, F#, etc).

Comment: dependiendo la base tambien podrias tener un programa que leyera los logs de cambios en las tablas, y eso informara de los cambios.. todo muy costoso, obviamente..

Answer (score 1):

Implementa un **Hibernate interceptor**, el cual se puede configurar para escuchar cualquier tipo de operacion P.E. Inser, update, delete. el interceptor es un intermediario entre la aplicacion y el gestor de BD, por lo que puedes disparar operaicones incluso antes de que la tarea principal afecte las tablas de la BD. ref. https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/